# Listview upload control

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, listview

I have a listview which has insert capabilities, one of the fields is an image field, how can I add an upload control to upload an image and store the file path, into the the database.

Alternatively I could have the file upload outside of the layout control then update the textbox in the layout with the file path.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the [FileUpload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) control into the ItemTemplate of your ListView.  Then you need to handle the appropriate event and use the `FileUploadControl.FileName` value to save the path to the DB.